How to automatically import Google Sheets into Looker Studio?

In my GDrive I have a folder /reports/.
In this folder appear daily new subfolders with creation timestamp as folder name.
Each timestamped subfolder always contain a single Google Sheet.
All Google Sheets have always the same table structure (same headings, same amount of columns).
First column always contain the date.

What is the way to automatically import these Google Sheets into Looker Studio?
The goal is to build a Looker time-series chart based on daily Google Sheets.
